# Access http interceptor from Angular component

Tags: angular

I am using a http interceptor in my angular project. I have a variable that I want to change at runtime that I can add various headers to. The basic setup of my interceptor is below

```
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public additionalHeaders: KeyValuePair[]


  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {.....
}
```

I am initializing this in my module as follows.

```
 providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HeaderInterceptor, deps: [AppConfigProvider, Router], multi: true }]
```

This all works fine but I cant think of a way to change the additionalHeaders property once the application is loaded. Is there a way to inject the interceptor into a component or perhaps a better way to do this altogether?

Comment: The point of an HttpInterceptor is to apply any rules you *always* want to apply to any http request. If there is a specific header you want to apply only in certain scenarios, those should go directly onto the construction of the http request.

Comment: I don't think adding headers for a component via an Interceptor is a good approach. Add the headers in the service for that component explicitly.

Comment: I dont agree, adding for example Authorization: bearer is common practice

Comment: In my case the interceptor is part of a framework used across multiple applications. One app needs different information in the header to another and the information within can change during the users session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the interceptor directly, why not have some form of state service or something that both services can interact with.

Your desired service can set some values and then your interceptor can read them, without the originating service needing to know if the existence of an interceptor at all.

Services can be injected into interceptor services just like any other.